# Get user by email or return null in cron

Tags: magento2, cron

How can i get user by his email, or return null if not found? I need to do this in cron.

This code works

```
$CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');

                        try {
                            $customerExists = $CustomerModel->get($email); //Here 1 means Store ID**
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            $customerExists = false;
                        }
```

But once I run it via cron, it returns an error that email is already in use, even when in try/catch block.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done some mistake

You have changes

**catch (Exception $e) {**

**to**

```
catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
.....
}
catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e){
...
}
```

**NoSuchEntityException** exception thrown by this class when 
`if a customer with the specified email does not exist`.

**LocalizedException** error thrown when other errors happen.

**SEE Defination**

```
/**
 * Retrieve customer.
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @param int|null $websiteId
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If customer with the specified email does not exist.
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function get($email, $websiteId = null);
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it, but why? Didnt "catch Exception $e" also catch NoSuchEntityException?

Comment: Magento2 use  different  type s of exception handling for API, so, it is introduce